# Catching JDBCConnectionExceptions in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hikaricp

In spring boot with hikari handling database connections, i want to catch, `JDBCConnectionException` exceptions or any other hibernate level exceptions, so that i can generate notifications when this happens. I have one `@ControllerAdvice` configured but, seems it doesn't come to that level but handled earlier.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionTranslator {

    @ExceptionHandler(JDBCConnectionException.class)
    public void handleJdbcConnectionException(JDBCConnectionException ex, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), ex.getMessage());
    }
```

I am using spring data repositories to access db.

```
WARN |PoolBase                      |2d33dd4e-46d6-11e9-9d35-2f44d962868c|conf-hikari-pool - Failed to validate connection ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 1f1135cd-94bf-4543-bfe8-687e10a40797 (The connection is closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
WARN |PoolBase                      |2d33dd4e-46d6-11e9-9d35-2f44d962868c|conf-hikari-pool - Failed to validate connection ConnectionID:2 ClientConnectionId: 28890cd1-16ad-43f9-b240-a9ae3aa2d45f (The connection is closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
WARN |SqlExceptionHelper            |2d33dd4e-46d6-11e9-9d35-2f44d962868c|SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR|SqlExceptionHelper            |2d33dd4e-46d6-11e9-9d35-2f44d962868c|conf-hikari-pool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 6010ms.
ERROR|SqlExceptionHelper            |2d33dd4e-46d6-11e9-9d35-2f44d962868c|The connection is closed.
```

Comment: hi @GhostCat I am not really sure, how to provide more details to this. I can give a code snippet of my exception handler but it doesn't going to do any help IMO.

Comment: @aravindaM it is very hard to understand problem just by looking at logs. Posting code will definitely help

Answer (score 1):

The code example that you have given will only catch exceptions that are thrown in the flow of a REST call. Many of the spring-data exceptions are thrown after the REST calls return during database commit. It is not possible to throw those exceptions in this fashion. The best way to handle those errors is to look at logs, push them to something like Splunk and generate alerts there.

Comment: Thank you @vinay-avasthi. Too bad not being able to do that.